# How to use timer interrupt from GPIO to control sampling period of ADC in BeagleBone Black by c++ code?

Tags: c++, linux-kernel, beagleboneblack, armv7, debian-jessie

I'm a university student, who need to study about making adc capturing in BeagleBone Black.

Everything goes really well. I can sampling the data from adc and even print the time stamp in each sample value. Then I check the sampling period of result which i got by using oscilloscope the check the wave from GPIO P8_10 by using "**BeagleBoneBlack-GPIO**" library  Finally I realized that the sampling period is not stable at all.

And I assumed that I supposed to use Interrupt timer in BeagleBone Black. But my root-skill is pretty low to make it by my own.

Anyway. How can i make Interrupt timer by c++ through GPIO because I need to used the interrupt timer to control the adc to make the steady and stable sampling period such as 3ms.

data below is which version I am using, the code, and the result right now also

> ```
> -BeagleBone Black 
> -Debian GNU/LInux 8.11 (jessie)
> -Linux 5.0.3-bone5
> -ARMv7 Processor rev2 (v7l)
> ```

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <sys/time.h>
    #include <time.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include<iostream>
    #include<fstream>
    #include<string>
    #include<sstream>
    #include<unistd.h>
    #include "GPIO/GPIOManager.h"
    #include "GPIO/GPIOConst.h"

    using namespace std;
    #define LIN0_PATH "/sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/in_voltage" 
    int readAnalog(int number){
            stringstream ss;
            ss << LIN0_PATH << number << "_raw";
            fstream fs;
            fs.open(ss.str().c_str(), fstream::in);
            fs >> number;
            fs.close(); 
     return number; 
     } 
     int main(int argc, char* argv[ ]){ 
     int i=0;       
     GPIO::GPIOManager* gp = GPIO::GPIOManager::getInstance();  
     int pin1 = GPIO::GPIOConst::getInstance()->getGpioByKey("P8_10");  
     gp->setDirection(pin1, GPIO::OUTPUT);

      char buffer[26];   
      int millisec;   
      struct tm* tm_info;   
      struct timeval tv;

    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);   
    millisec = lrint(tv.tv_usec/1000.0); // Round to nearest millisec   
    if (millisec>=1000) {                
        millisec -=1000;
        tv.tv_sec++;
        }   tm_info = localtime(&tv.tv_sec);   
    strftime(buffer, 26, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S", tm_info);   
    cout<<"print date and time"<<buffer<<":"<<millisec << endl;

    for (int j=0;j<100;j++){  
      gp->setValue(pin1, GPIO::HIGH);  
      float value[j] = readAnalog(0)*(1.8/4096) ;  
      gp->setValue(pin1, GPIO::LOW);  
      usleep(300);  
    }    

    for (int j=0;j<100;j++){   
      cout << fixed;   
      cout.precision(3);   
      cout <<i<<";"<<value<< endl;

    i++; }

    return 0; }
```

And these are command to run the my file

> `g++ GPIO/GPIOConst.cpp GPIO/GPIOManager.cpp try.cpp`

then

> `./a.out`

and this is the result

> ```
> print date and time10/04/2019 17:02:27:460
> 0;1.697
> 1;1.697
> 2;1.695
> 3;1.693
> 4;1.694
> 5;1.693
> 6;1.693
> 7;1.692
> 8;1.691
> 9;1.692
> 10;1.693
> 11;1.692
> 12;1.694
> 13;1.694
> 14;1.694
> 15;1.692
> 16;1.695
> 17;1.692
> 18;1.693
> 19;1.694
> 20;1.693
> 21;1.691
> 22;1.692
> 23;1.693
> 24;1.691
> 25;1.693
> 26;1.693
> 27;1.693
> 28;1.694
> 29;1.691
> 30;1.694
> 31;1.693
> 32;1.695
> 33;1.691
> 34;1.694
> 35;1.693
> 36;1.693
> 37;1.691
> 38;1.693
> 39;1.691
> 40;1.692
> 41;1.694
> 42;1.692
> 43;1.692
> 44;1.693
> 45;1.692
> 46;1.694
> 47;1.693
> 48;1.693
> 49;1.692
> 50;1.692
> 51;1.692
> 52;1.691
> 53;1.690
> 54;1.691
> 55;1.692
> 56;1.693
> 57;1.692
> 58;1.692
> 59;1.692
> 60;1.694
> 61;1.694
> 62;1.694
> 63;1.694
> 64;1.693
> 65;1.692
> 66;1.693
> 67;1.692
> 68;1.693
> 69;1.693
> 70;1.692
> 71;1.692
> 72;1.693
> 73;1.694
> 74;1.693
> 75;1.694
> 76;1.693
> 77;1.692
> 78;1.694
> 79;1.692
> 80;1.692
> 81;1.692
> 82;1.692
> 83;1.692
> 84;1.694
> 85;1.694
> 86;1.693
> 87;1.693
> 88;1.694
> 89;1.693
> 90;1.693
> 91;1.692
> 92;1.694
> 93;1.691
> 94;1.694
> 95;1.693
> 96;1.691
> 97;1.692
> 98;1.693
> 99;1.694
> ```

[and this is what i got from oscilloscope][1]

> [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJSRe.jpg

It will be really great if there are anyone who would love to give me some advice. And If there are something concerning you guys. Please feel free to ask me.

Best Regard

Peeranut Noonurak